# Creating column for every group in group by

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have a table `T` which has entries as follows:

```
id   | type   | value   | 
-------------------------
1    | A      | 7
1    | B      | 8
2    | A      | 9
2    | B      | 10
3    | A      | 11
3    | B      | 12
1    | C      | 13
2    | C      | 14
```

For each type, I want a different column. Since the number of types is exhaustive, I would like all different types to be enumerated and a corresponding column for each. I wanted to make `id` a primary key for the table.

So, the desired output is something like:

```
id   | A's value | B's value | C's value
------------------------------------------
1    | 7         | 8         | 13
2    | 9         | 10        | 14
3    | 11        | 12        | NULL
```

Please note that this is a simplified version. The actual table `T` is derived from a much bigger table using `group by`. And for each group, I would like a separate column. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when type = 'A' then value end) as a_value,
       max(case when type = 'B' then value end) as b_value,
       max(case when type = 'C' then value end) as c_value
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: On a side note, is there a way to automate this, i.e., without having to manually list down the `types` explicitly, make sql iterate through all the groups?

Comment: @ghost . . . This is called a dynamic pivot and there is not a simple solution as a `select`.  You need to do some programming.  Here is a discussion of this topic:  https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008TTgZASA1/what-is-the-best-way-to-dynamically-pivot-a-table.

Comment: Note - that post was prior to JS Stored Procedures.  You could create a stored procedure that dynamically generates the PIVOT statement (mentioned in Rich's answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into the PIVOT function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html

The main blocker with this function though is the list of values for the pivot_column needs to be
pre-determined.  To do this, I normally use the LISTAGG function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html

I've included a query below to show you how to build that string,
and doing this together in a script like
Python or even a Stored Procedure should be fairly straightforward (build the pivot_column, build the aggregate/pivot command, execute the aggregate/pivot command).

I hope this helps...Rich

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE monthly_sales(
    empid   INT, 
    amount  INT, 
    month   TEXT)
AS SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 10000, 'JAN'),
    (1, 400, 'JAN'),
    (2, 4500, 'JAN'),
    (2, 35000, 'JAN'),
    (1, 5000, 'FEB'),
    (1, 3000, 'FEB'),
    (2, 200, 'FEB'),
    (2, 90500, 'FEB'),
    (1, 6000, 'MAR'),
    (1, 5000, 'MAR'),
    (2, 2500, 'MAR'),
    (2, 9500, 'MAR'),
    (1, 8000, 'APR'),
    (1, 10000, 'APR'),
    (2, 800, 'APR'),
    (2, 4500, 'APR');


SELECT * 
FROM monthly_sales
    PIVOT(SUM(amount) 
    FOR month IN ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR'))
    AS p
ORDER BY empid;

SELECT LISTAGG( DISTINCT  ''''||month||'''',  ', ' ) 
FROM monthly_sales;
```